# Property [name] does not exist on this collection instance using maatwebsite/excel:~2.1.0

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

Am trying to import Excel file in Laravel 5.5 and insert the data in the database. following this tutorial.  https://laratutorials.wordpress.com/2017/10/03/how-to-import-excel-file-in-laravel-5-and-insert-the-data-in-the-database-laravel-tutorials/comment-page-1/#comment-262

i have been able to get and validate selected file.
but an getting this error: Property [name] does not exist on this collection instance.

```
  public function import(Request $request){
    //validate the xls file
    $this->validate($request, array(
        'file'      => 'required'
    ));

    if($request->hasFile('file')){
        $extension = File::extension($request->file->getClientOriginalName());
        if ($extension == "xlsx" || $extension == "xls" || $extension == "csv") {

            $path = $request->file->getRealPath();
            $data = Excel::load($path, function($reader) {
            })->get();
            if(!empty($data) && $data->count()){

                foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
                    $insert[] = [
                    'name' => $value->name,
                    'email' => $value->email,
                    'phone' => $value->phone,
                    ];
                }

                if(!empty($insert)){

                    $insertData = DB::table('students')->insert($insert);
                    if ($insertData) {
                        Session::flash('success', 'Your Data has successfully imported');
                    }else {                        
                        Session::flash('error', 'Error inserting the data..');
                        return back();
                    }
                }
            }

            return back();

        }else {
            Session::flash('error', 'File is a '.$extension.' file.!! Please upload a valid xls/csv file..!!');
            return back();
        }
    }
}
```

dd($data) output this

```
      SheetCollection {#609 ▼
  #title: ""
  #items: array:3 [▼
    0 => RowCollection {#412 ▼
      #heading: array:3 [▼
        0 => "name"
        1 => "email"
        2 => "phone"
      ]
      #title: "Sheet1"
      #items: array:3 [▼
        0 => CellCollection {#575 ▼
          #title: null
          #items: array:3 [▼
            "name" => "emma"
            "email" => "emma@yahoo.com"
            "phone" => 89889898.0
          ]
        }
        1 => CellCollection {#621 ▼
          #title: null
          #items: array:3 [▼
            "name" => "Godstime John"
            "email" => "jgodstime10@yahoo.com"
            "phone" => 909989898.0
          ]
        }
        2 => CellCollection {#414 ▼
          #title: null
          #items: array:3 [▼
            "name" => "John Emma"
            "email" => "jgh@email.com"
            "phone" => 9090898.0
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
    1 => RowCollection {#571 ▼
      #heading: array:1 [▼
        0 => ""
      ]
      #title: "Sheet2"
      #items: []
    }
    2 => RowCollection {#572 ▼
      #heading: array:1 [▼
        0 => ""
      ]
      #title: "Sheet3"
      #items: []
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to be able to upload the row in my excel file (name, email, phone) to student table in my db that has fields (id, name, email, phone).
i followed all the step in the above link. yet still i get the aforementioned error message.

Comment: Can you add the results of `dd($data);`?

Comment: i have done that @Aditya Thakur

Comment: Can you try changing the `$value->name`, to `$value->items['name']`, and same for others.

Comment: i get this Property [items] does not exist on this collection instance.

Comment: Sorry my bad, can you try `$value['items']['name']`

Comment: Undefined index: items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach ($data[0] as $key => $value) {
  // dd($value->name);

 $insert[] = [
 'name' => $value->name,
 'email' => $value->email,
 'phone' => $value->phone,
 ];
}
```

Comment: It's always good to add an explanation of the code, or at least an explanation of why the OP's code doesn't work and how yours fixes it.

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the Solution with explanation.**

**This is your current code of map method.**

```
public function map($user): array
{
    return [
        $user->id,
        $user->email
    ];
}
```

**But I have updated the user's table data. I have passed the users data from the controller in the constructor like this. and then in the foreach loop under map method, I'll store the data in the array and then return the array.**
**I hope, this explained the solution.**
**Here is my code.**

```
<?php

namespace App\Exports;

use App\Models\User;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\Exportable;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromQuery;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithMapping;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\FromCollection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ShouldAutoSize;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadingRow;

class UsersExport implements FromCollection, ShouldAutoSize, WithMapping
{
    use Exportable;
    protected $users;

    public function __construct(array $users)
    {
        $this->users = $users;
    }

    public function collection()
    {
        return collect($this->users);
    }

    public function map($user): array
    {
        foreach ($this->users[0] as $key => $value) {
           $user[] = [
           'id' => $value->id,
           'email' => $value->email
           ];
          }
        return $user;  
    }
}
```

Controller Code

```
if($request->export_users == 'true'){
    $usersExport = User::get();
    $export = new UsersExport([
        $usersExport
    ]);
    return Excel::download($export, 'users.xlsx');
}
```

Note: Remember to import dependencies in the controller.